# How can I edit my product page in woocommerce in installed theme

Tags: wordpress

I have installed My travel theme and I have got a by default product page, it's totally correct I just want to make the design changes on that page, for eg. I am having product image on my left side and booking details on right side, so I want that booking side to my left side, and product side on my right How can I Do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that will help you:

You'll need to override the single product page template in your child theme.

1. If you don't have a child theme create one. You can manually create it or better use this plugin to create a child theme: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-child-theme-generator/ and activate it.
2. Create a new folder structure in child theme /woocommerce/templates/
3. You need to copy the relevant product page templates from your parent theme to the child theme.

The most relevant ones will be **single-product.php**, **content-product.php**, and folder **single-product**

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you help me to do this, as i can't do this i can give you the access to do this. Please help it will really save my problem and me also.

Comment: Hi Ayush, please DM me with details. I'll help you out.